# Flutter bluetooth glucometer

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm making an application in Flutter that should be connected to a gtech lite glucometer via Bluetooth. I would like to receive glucose measurements but I didn't find a way to do this, I read the features that have the read property but none of them came with glucose measurements.
I'm using flutter_blue_plus

I would like to know how I can display glucose measurements in my application

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which service and profile are you querying?  One of those defined [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/?types=adopted&keyword=glucose)? Or does the 'gtech lite glucometer' use its own custom service and profile?